# Create em converter function in SASS not SCSS

Tags: sass

I am new to SASS and Compass trying to create one function which can convert passed pixel value to em. I found one tutorial but it is for SCSS and that doesn't work with SASS.

Even I have checked on SASS website but seem they have most document for SCSS and not everything they have describe for SASS.

Here what I am writing

```
@function em($px, $base: 24px)
    @return ($px / $base) * 1em
```

Also using vertical-rythem in my project and tried this to but than again giving error for `$base-font-size`

```
@function em($px, $base: $base-font-size)
    @return ($px / $base) * 1em
```

So when I use it as

```
font-size: em(16px)
```

It should convert to `1em` in output

Answer (score 1):

The function you have seems correct. Just make sure you have defined `$base-font-size` with a value such as 16px.

The above mixin you have should also work

```
$base-font-size: 16px;
@function em($px, $base: $base-font-size) {
@return ($px / $base ) * 1em; 
}
```

Now you can call `font-size: em(16px);` and it should work 
You can also call this function with an optional base, sometimes you might want to calculate on a base that's not 16px.

Please also look up http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/less-mixin-for-rem-font-sizing/ for rem font sizing. You might want to skip em because they have a nesting problem http://css-tricks.com/why-ems/

For a more detailed version of the above mixin, where you can call

`border: emCalc (10 20 30 40);`

Where you don't have to repeat the px value again and again and you may have 1 to 4 values within, check the mixin in Zurb's foundation `_global.scss`

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss#L183